# JSON Parsing in AngularJS Service

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

I have Angular service and in that service I have a code:

```
this.testMethod = function( ) {
    this.jsonTest = "[{'id':'123','title':'XYZ','id2':'456','status':2}]";
    this.parseTest(this.jsonTest);
};

this.parseTest = function(jsonTest) {
    var jsonTestObj = JSON.parse(jsonTest); // I get error hear
}
```

Test method is getting called on `ng-click` event.
Error that I am getting while testing in latest chrome browser:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token ' at Object.parse (native)
......
```

I tried multiple things to fix it but nothing seems to work.
Every time I get undefined value error.

Basically I want to parse JSON object and get the values.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `[{'id':'123','title':'XYZ','id2':'456','status':2}]` is not a valid JSON..

Comment: It should be in `double` quotes(`"`)..ex: `[{"id":"123"}]`

Comment: Another tip I have for you is: don't use `this`. The `this` in controller and in `testMethod` refer to different things. This will cause weird issues. Rather, use `var v = this` in controller, and `v.testMethod` and `v.jsonTest`. This'll guarantee that both the things refer to the same `this`.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, what is the difference between `var myfoo = function(){ ... }` and `function myfoo(){ .... }` are both same? Why it is good to use `v.testMethod()` way, please explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this

```
this.jsonTest = '[{"id":"123","title":"XYZ","id2":"456","status": "2"}]';
```

Or this

```
this.jsonTest = "[{\"id\":\"123\",\"title\":\"XYZ\",\"id2\":\"456\",\"status\": \"2\"}]";
```

You either need to use `'` outside or `"` outside and escape the quotes inside.

Both the key and value need to be in **double** quotes.

Comment: For reference, read http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/

Comment: Oh I was not knowing that, that for the explanation.

Comment: You're welcome, I first came across the single vs double quote thing when I was first using serialization myself. I used to think too that javascript and json objects are the same. But json objects must have the quotes.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use double quotes in your string, other than that your code should work.

To quote from [specification](http://json.org/)

> A value can be a string in double quotes, or a number, or true or false or null, or an object or an array. These structures can be nested.

Answer (score -2):

Your JSON is not valid. Always check your JSON integrity in those cases, i personaly use

http://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Your validator marks the json in the question as valid. That's not so.

Comment: not it doesn't:  Error: Parse error on line 1:
[{ 'id': '123', 'title
---^
Expecting 'STRING', '}', got 'undefined'

Comment: I'm getting 'valid json' for everything: http://i.imgur.com/dEVu3fM.png Note the last ' is missing. Even then, ' should not be inside. http://i.imgur.com/tI4qj1d.png Another.

Comment: In JSON, you have to use double quote (") ... single quote (') is an invalid character ... If you want to use single quote, you have to escape it.